# $_POST array to MySQL _v2

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post

I am trying to update a MySQL database via $_POST Array and FORM. This is the code I have written, simplified.

In page 1 I get an array of 5, and it’s only the last “text box” that can be used for updating, and it updates the whole column, all 5. I want to be able to update a single cell.

I have asked this question once, but whiteout the code, so here goes:

Page 1

```
<form method="POST" action="showpost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" ><tr><td>
<?php 
$host = "***";
$username1 = "***";
$password1 = "***";
$db_name = "***";
$tbl_name = "***";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username1", "$password1") or die("Can’t connect ");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No connection to table ");

$foresp1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name"); 
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($foresp1))  
{
$example = $data[3];
echo "<input type='text' value='$example' name='examplearray[]' size='10'><br>";

}

?>

</td></tr></table>

<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

Page 2 - (showpost.php)

```
<?php
$host = "***";
$username1 = "***";
$password1 = "***";
$db_name = "***";
$tbl_name = "***";

mysql_connect("$host", "$username1", "$password1") or die("Can’t connect ");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No connection to table ");

{
foreach($_POST['examplearray'] as $value)
{
mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET  example_cell = '$value'");
}
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: At a quick glance, you don't seem to be limited your UPDATE query to a particular row. Instead, it will update all rows as it is written.

Comment: you should have WHERE condition in your query .. show you database table here ..

Comment: You are vulenrable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com) and definitely are NOT writing your update query correctly anyways: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_%28SQL%29

Comment: You're not doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) here and you have some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that could lead to disaster if this is on the public internet. [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and provides a simple, reliable way of adding data to queries. A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) outlines the recommended best practices when interfacing with databases.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet you should try to adapt your query and data to when inserting.
I still dont understand what data you have so i can not be specific.

```
<?php

$host = "***";
$username1 = "***";
$password1 = "***";
$db_name = "***";
$tbl_name = "***";
// pdo is built into to newer versions of php, you should be able to do this
// this will help eliminate sql injection issues (data sanitation)
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $username1, $password1);

if (!$db) {

    die('no connection to table');
}

// you havent posted whats in $_POST and the inputs you have are also vague...
// lets say you want to update a name or a address and you have the row id
// so post has the following
// $_POST['name'] = 'some data the user posted from the form or a long name';
// $_POST['address'] = 'some other long data';
// $_POST['id'] = 16;

// you may want to check if the data is posted, not just assume the data is there
$dataToInsert = array(
    ':name' => $_POST['name'],
    ':bindvalue' => $_POST['address'],
    ':id' => $_POST['id']
);


// this creates a statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE $tbl_name SET name = :name, address = :bindvalue WHERE row_id = :id");

// by executing your statement like this, you help protect against sql injection
$result = $stmt->execute($dataToInsert);
```

?>

Comment: I have tried to follow you example to the letter, but no result... 
Your example goes for - Page 2 - correct? And therefore you see no issues in - Page 1 - ?

Answer (score 0):

a simple adaptation of my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22465820/661872), you basically set the row id of the row within the `name="update['.$row['id'].']"` form, then use that to know which row to update.. I dont write mysql_ functions so this is how you do it in PDO.

```
<?php 
//connect to database using PDO
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databasename", 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}
?>


<form method="POST" action="showpost.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT id, example_cell FROM tbl_name";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($result as $row)
{
    echo '<input type="text" value="'.htmlentities($row['example_cell']).'" name="update['.$row['id'].']" size="10"><br>';
}

?>
<input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

### showpost.php

```
<?php
//connect to database using PDO
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=databasename", 'dbuser', 'dbpassword');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
}catch (Exception $e){
    die('Cannot connect to mySQL server.');
}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['update'])){
    //prepare the query
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE tbl_name SET example_cell = :value WHERE id = :id");

    foreach($_POST['update'] as $key=>$value)
    {
        //do update
        $stmt->execute(array(':value' => $value,
                              ':id'    => $key));
    }
}

?>
```

untested, hope it helps.

Comment: I have tested this, and I can't get to work at all. There is an error in - Page 1 - in your example, and I can't find it.

Was both my Page 1 and Page 2 so off target, that they are useless?
To me it seems that I must somehow rewrite the UPDATE command, but just don't know to what.

Comment: yeah your need to change a few things mainly the mysql login details, name of the table in the query `tbl_name`. Its not a copy and paste solution, *teach a man to fish and all that*... also assigning table names in variables is just bad practice it shouldn't be done, only if your implementing some prefix to the table to stop collisions with other scripts. **Let me know the error and show me the proper table structure, by exporting it from phpmyadmin or such then, ill tell you what's wrong...**